# How can I change the background color of focused element for few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here the code lays focus on second div. Now I want to set background color for focused element to another color for few secs and then fade back to it's original color. How to do that?

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus();
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fis">hello
</div>
<div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
</div>
<div id='thr'>john
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following way you can change color for some time period. First it will to yellow after few seconds it back to green.

```js
$(function(){
  
   $("#two").focus();
  
   setTimeout(function() {
        $('#two').css("background-color", "green");
    }, 2000);
  
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:yellow; transition:background-color 1s ease;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fis">hello
</div>
<div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
</div>
<div id='thr'>john
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is solution using `setTimeout` on `focus` event.

```js
$(function(){
    $('div').on('focus', function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.addClass('highlight');
       setTimeout(function(){
         $this.removeClass('highlight');
       }, 2000);
    })
    $("#two").focus();
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
#fis.highlight{background-color:yellow;}
#two.highlight{background-color:yellow;}
#thr.highlight{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fis">hello
</div>
<div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
</div>
<div id='thr'>john
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I think u missed something there is no color change in snippet

Comment: 'mr' tab is highlighted (yellow) at the beginning and after 2 sec becomes green, isn'the it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#two").focus(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
         setTimeout(function(){

             $("#two").css("background-color","yellow");
        },1000);
    });    
});
```

try this...

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help the OP understand your answer better, and help future searchers.